# .NET 5 option missing from new project wizard in Visual Studio Pro 2019 v16.8.1

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I've installed .NET 5.0 SDK and upgraded Visual Studio to 16.8.1 but the option doesn't come up for WinForm apps?

[image]

Comment: You've chosen a "Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)" project, you want a "Windows Forms App (.NET)" project.  Notice the subtle difference.

Comment: @jmoerdyk WTH Visual Studio Team ! Thank you for that.

Comment: @jmoerdyk Post as answer so you get points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're selected the `Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)` project type, which is the the non-Core version of .NET.

For the .NET 5 version, you want the `Windows Forms App (.NET)` project type.